# Reporting map mistake in Positron?

Tags: carto

While displaying a Positron map from cartoDB, I noticed a mistake about a name (CAYENNE) which is bigger than it should be.

[image: CAYENNE in NORMANDY FRANCE]

CAYENNE is only a street name, there are no cities called CAYENNE in this area. 
How can I report this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to report it is by opening an issue in the CartoDB basemaps repository:
https://github.com/CartoDB/CartoDB-basemaps/issues